# How to copy conditional formatting from one sheet to another via apche POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am facing a situation where I have to copy conditional formatting from one excel sheet to another.

This is what I tried;

```
SheetConditionalFormatting sscf= source.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

SheetConditionalFormatting dscf= destination.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

for(int i=0;i<sscf.getNumConditionalFormattings();i++)
    dscf.addConditionalFormatting(sscf.getConditionalFormattingAt(i));
```

source and destination both are XSSF.

But when I try to open destination sheet, excel showing a message that there are some errors in the sheet and do I want to recover it? If I click yes the sheet opens but conditional formatting are not applying correctly.

After repairing excel is showing a message like;

**Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content**

In this case my condition formatting is like *If there is a space in a range of cells then background of that cell will be gray*

But I can not give it hard coded in my destination sheet(though I don't know whether it is possible or not) because there can be different formatting in source sheet.

Can you please mention if I doing something wrong?

Comment: The `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet` is an `Interface` and not a `Class`. So what exactly is source and destination? Are both sheets in one workbook? Is the workbook `HSSF` or `XSSF`?

Comment: Ops.. sorry. Workbook is XSSF.

Comment: Are both sheets in one workbook? Seems as if not. But please confirm. And please provide the used formula for your *If there is a space in a range of cells then...* to make this behavior reproducible.

Comment: No @AxelRichter

Comment: Both sheets are not in one workbook and I didn't use any formula manually. I go to conditional formatting window to set it from ms excel @AxelRichter

Comment: The copying of `ConditionalFormatting` objects from one sheet to another as mentioned in [addConditionalFormatting(ConditionalFormatting cf)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/SheetConditionalFormatting.html#addConditionalFormatting(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ConditionalFormatting)) works only for sheets in the same workbook. This is because only the rules are copied but not the formatting which is not located in the sheet but in the styles part oft the workbook. Sorry, no easy solution for this.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter, is there any way to copy the formatting as well or we can't even do that? Thanks

Comment: @Shashank Gupta: Nothing is impossible. But as said formatting is not located in the sheet but in the styles part of the workbook. The rules in the sheet only have Ids to link. And there are so much possible kinds of formatting. So no **easy** solution for this. Much too broad to show here.

Answer (score 1):

That's how it worked for me:

```
XSSFWorkbook existingWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new File("c:/test1.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook brandNewWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(true);
XSSFSheet existingSheet = existingWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
CTWorksheet ctWorksheet = existingSheet.getCTWorksheet();
List<CTConditionalFormatting> formattingList = ctWorksheet.getConditionalFormattingList();
XSSFSheet sheet = brandNewWorkbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
for (CTConditionalFormatting cf : formattingList) {
    CTConditionalFormatting newCf = sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewConditionalFormatting();
    newCf.xsetSqref(cf.xgetSqref());
    newCf.setCfRuleArray(cf.getCfRuleList().toArray(new CTCfRule[]{}));
}

CTDxfs dxfs = existingWorkbook.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet().getDxfs();
brandNewWorkbook.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet().setDxfs(dxfs);

try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/test2.xlsx"))) {
    brandNewWorkbook.write(out);
}
```